# android studio "USB device not found"

Tags: android

I'd like to start by saying that I am using android studio(1.0.1) with an Android (v4.1.2) phone.

Android studio is not recognizing any device connected.
I have already set run configuration to usb device,
I think my problem is with Google usb driver,
how to check if it is working?
Thank you

Comment: Have you turned on usb debugging on your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the above help, try doing adb kill-server and adb start-server, then do adb devices and see if device is detected.

Comment: well i am new to android,how adb kill-server and adb start-server is done?

Comment: Attach your phone to the computer. Open a command window and type the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your Operational System recognize/mount the device? See if you can access the folders inside the device. If you won't you may install the compatible driver.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Which phone do you got?
ask yourself the following quistions first:
 1. Did you install all the phone drivers?
 2. Are you in developer mode with usb debugging on?